# Expectation of exponential of a function of independent Rademacher r.v.'s involving the error function

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, expectation

Let $Z,Z'\in\{-1,1\}^n$ be two independent vectors of i.i.d. Rademacher r.v.'s, where $1\leq n \leq d$ are two integers ($d\gg 1$). I am trying to get an upper bound on
$$
\mathbb{E}_{ZZ'}\left[ \exp\left({k\left(e^{\sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm{Erf}(\varepsilon Z_j /\sqrt{d})} -1\right)\left(e^{\sum_{j'=1}^n \mathrm{Erf}(\varepsilon Z'_{j'} /\sqrt{d})} -1\right)}\right) \right] \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
where $t\geq 1$, $\varepsilon \in(0,1]$, $k\geq 1$ is an integer, and $\mathrm{Erf}$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). In particular, I am interested in the dependence on $n$: since
$$
\mathrm{Erf}(x) \operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to\ 0} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}x
$$
I expect that, for $n = n(d) \ll \sqrt{d}$, $(\dagger)$ should be roughly
$$
\mathbb{E}_{ZZ'}\left[ \exp\left({\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{\varepsilon^2 k}{d}\sum_{j,j'} Z_jZ'_{j'}}\right) \right] \leq e^{C \frac{\varepsilon^4 k^2}{d^2}\cdot n^2}
$$
(the last bound for $d$ big enough). But I'm unclear if the above qualitative behavior still holds for $n \gg \sqrt{d}$: do we still get that $n^2$ dependence in the exponent?

---

Note: I am actually interested in the quantity
$$
\mathbb{E}_{ZZ'}\left[ \exp\left({k \left(\prod_{j=1}^n  (1+\mathrm{Erf}(\varepsilon Z_j /\sqrt{d}))-1\right)\left(\prod_{j'=1}^n  (1+\mathrm{Erf}(\varepsilon Z'_{j'} /\sqrt{d}))-1\right)}\right) \right] \tag{$\ddagger$}
$$
(same questions), but $(\dagger)$ is similar and hopefully a bit cleaner to analyze.

Comment: @MattF. Sure, why not. I made these changes, roughly.

Comment: Thanks! I had not noticed the double-exponential before

Comment: While we're suggesting simplifications---you might want to define $\delta := \varepsilon/\sqrt{d}$ to lower the number of parameters. (Also, this is probably dumb, but it seems like things get a lot nicer if you write the outer exponential as a Taylor series.)

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz I see the advantage of the reparamerization (although it makes the interpretetaion of the relation $n$ v. $d/\varepsilon^2$ less clear). But I'm curious about what you mean with the series expansion: this would bring powers of $\sum_{j,j'} Z_j Z'_{j'}$ to handle, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, but I guess you can apply independence to write this as $\sum_i \mathbb{E}[f_i(Z_1,\ldots, Z_n)]\mathbb{E}[f_i(Z_1',\ldots, Z_n')]$, which seems like a pretty big win to me. Again, this is probably stupid, but it's what I would try.

Answer (score 1):

*(This was supposed to be a comment, but I wrote in the Answer box because I don't have the privilege to comment. Apologies for the confusion.)*

Every $Z_i = \pm 1$, so you have $\mathrm{Erf}(Z_i \delta) = Z_i \mathrm{Erf}(\delta) \equiv Z_i \tau$, and the products become $(1 + \tau)^b (1 - \tau)^{n - b}$ where $b$ follows the Binomial distribution $B(n, 1/2)$, and the same for the primed quantities. The expectation is then $$\mathbb{E}_{bb'}\left[\exp\left({k \left((1 + \tau)^b (1 - \tau)^{n-b}-1\right)\left((1 + \tau)^{b'} (1 - \tau)^{n-b'}))-1\right)}\right) \right] .$$
Perhaps this allows you to get the kind of bound you are looking for. You have $0 < \tau < 1$, so you can bracket $(1 + \tau)^b(1 - \tau)^{n-b}$ by $(1-\tau)^n$ and $(1+\tau)^n$. Without having too good an idea about how to proceed, I would naively expect the expectation to behave like $\exp\bigl(k \, (1+\tau)^{2n})\bigr)$ as $n$ increases. A quick Mathematica experiment with $k = 1.23$, $\delta = 0.1$ seems to bear that out, but there could be all kinds of things going wrong here.

[image]

(Since you now have only two r.v.s to contend with, you can compute the expectation explicitly to get some additional insight, at least until the arithmetic overflows for large $n$.)